# Getting Value from specified Key - Firebase/Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have run into an issue where I have each child off the root be a separate user account with a object (converted to string through gson). I create each user in the database during user registration.

```
DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().getRoot();
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid(), "");
root.updateChildren(map);
```

Then save the user object in it using this method

```
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(this);
databaseReference.setValue(json);
```

Now I want to be able to pull the json from the firebase database but I can only get the `userID` key not the value. I am trying to avoid using a listener also.

This is how my database looks now:

```
-myapp-aaf46

      -(userID): {json string}
```

I need to be able to get json string but I can only get it to return `userId`

Comment: The only way to retrieve data from the Firebase Database with the Android SDK is by attaching a listener. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write